# Resynthesize intermediate values with boost::spirit::qi

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Given a grammar that synthesizes a user-defined type, how can I write another grammar that:

1. Reuses the first grammar.
2. Synthesizes a second, distinct type, using the values underlying the first type?

In the example below, I've followed the Boost Spirit documentation to create a parser, `foo_parser`, that synthesizes a value of type `foo_struct`. I'd like to write a second parser, `bar_parser`, that reuses `foo_parser` but synthesizes a different (but obviously similar) value of type `bar_struct`. My naive example, commented out, causes spectacular g++ fireworks. :)

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

namespace s  {
  using namespace boost::spirit;
  using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
  using namespace boost::spirit::ascii;
}

struct foo_struct {
  int i;
  char c;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  foo_struct,
  (int, i)
  (char, c)
)

struct bar_struct {
  int i;
  char c;
  int j;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct foo_parser : s::grammar<Iterator, foo_struct()>
{
  foo_parser() : foo_parser::base_type(start) {
    start %= s::int_ >> s::char_ ;
  }

  s::rule<Iterator, foo_struct()> start;
};

/*
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  bar_struct,
  (int, i)
  (char, c)
  (int, j)
)

template <typename Iterator>
struct bar_parser : s::grammar<Iterator, bar_struct()>
{
  bar_parser() : bar_parser::base_type(start) {
    // reuse a foo_parser
    start %= foo >> s::int_ ;
  }

  foo_parser<Iterator> foo;
  s::rule<Iterator, bar_struct()> start;
};

*/
```

Comment: I did not have time to run it through a compiler but I think the declaration of foo in your bar_parser is wrong. Should it not be: `foo_parser<Iterator, foo_struct()> foo`

Comment: @André No. `foo_parser`takes only one template argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've previously devised this - somewhat - hacky way to address things

```
struct mybase { int a,b; };
struct myderived : mybase 
 { 
    mybase& base;
    int c,d; 

     myderived() : base(*this) { }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(mybase,    (int,a)(int,b));
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(myderived, (mybase,base)(int,c)(int,d));
```

I'd much prefer a solution based on BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT, but I wasn't able to get it to work, see also the [spirit-general] mailing list:

- http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/struct-derived-struct-fusion-adapted-and-the-sequence-operator-td4259090.html
- or [search the list for `derived base`](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=2672582&query=derived+base)

Here's a full sample of that:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>

struct mybase             { int a,b; };
struct myderived : mybase { 
    myderived() : base(*this) { }
    mybase& base;
    int c,d; 
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(mybase,    (int,a)(int,b));
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(myderived, (mybase,base)(int,c)(int,d));

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

    const char input[] = "1 2 3 4";
    const char *f(input), *l(f+strlen(input));

    rule<const char*, mybase()   , space_type> base_     = int_ >> int_;
    rule<const char*, myderived(), space_type> derived_  = base_ >> int_ >> int_;

    myderived data;
    bool ok = phrase_parse(f,l,derived_,space,data);

    if (ok) std::cout << "data: " << data.a << ", " << data.b << ", " << data.c << ", " << data.d << "\n";
    else    std::cerr << "whoops\n";

    if (f!=l)
        std::cerr << "left: '" << std::string(f,l) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
data: 1, 2, 3, 4
```